# What video containers allow monaural audio?

Tags: audio, video, mono, muxer

I want to reduce video file's size and, instead encoding mono as two identical stereo channels, encode it as a one-channel mono. But will I be able to mux this true mono with video? I'm asking, because I've never seen an FFMPEG or MediaInfo report showing audio as "mono".

Comment: Try it and see™

Comment: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/AudioChannelManipulation

Comment: @TomYan: That's a bad suggestion™; often encoders will let you mux things in ways that go a bit outside the spec, and which might play in one player but not another.

Comment: @user1686 Well you never know anyway. It might not work even when your muxed file are totally spec-conforming, and as you implied, the muxing tool might not be doing the exact right thing. If you want to just get things *working* (for you), you try (with what you use), end of story. If you are "archiving" and want to make sure everything you use is doing it *right* (*before* you *use* it), IMHO it'd be a whole different story / question then.

Comment: The audio uses far less space than the video. If you *must* shrink the audio portion, use a lower bitrate.,

Comment: My original audio is true mono--I thought it would be ridiculous to expand it to stereo just to be able to mux it with video.

Comment: Audio does not always use far less space than video. When video consists of still images, like a presentation, video bandwidth can be very low, and if the presentation is eleven hours long, it begins to make sense to avoid unneccessarily increasing the size of the audio.